# Understanding PHP External Classes

Tags: php, api

I want to access a method from an external class, within another file.

I have an external class, let's say:

**external/file.php**

```
class ExternalClass {
  private $myClient;

  const CONSTANT = 'some/path';

  public function _constructor($myClient) {
    $this->myClient = $myClient;
  }

  public function getSome($information) { // Need to access this function
    $data = new StdObject();
    $data->information = $information;
    $result = $this->myClient->post(
      self::CONSTANT,
      $data
    );
    return($result['code'] == 200 ? json_decode($result['body']) : false);
  }

  public static function instance($SETTINGS) {
    return new ExternalClass(new MyClient($SETTINGS['externalclass']['host']));
  }

}
```

... I would like to reference this class in another file.

**internal/file.php**

```
include_once('external/file.php');

$externalClassInstance = ExternalClass::instance($SETTINGS); // line 3
$externalClass = new ExternalClass(); // line 4
$externalClassGetSome = $externalClass->getSome($information);  // line 5
```

The problem is, I'm not sure if I'm correctly referencing the *external* methods inside the *internal* file.

Is "Line 3" even necessary?

Also, the addition of *Line 5 code* breaks any code after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I don't know why you would need line 3.
Secondly you seem to have the answer right there

```
include_once('external/file.php');
$externalClass = new ExternalClass(); // line 4
$externalClassGetSome = $externalClass->getSome($information);
```

Comment: Thanks fancy. Its good to know Line 3 is not necessary. For some reason - Line 5 breaks the code, I was wondering if there was something wrong with the structure.

Answer (score 0):

try to change from

```
 include_once('external/file.php');
```

to

```
 include_once('../external/file.php');
```

becauase its in external directory and your file is in internal directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was just an example - but you're absolutely right, pathing would be incorrect here if I was to really use this as is.

Comment: for this $externalClassInstance = ExternalClass::instance($SETTINGS); is correct for static method however you can call using object also. like $externalClassGetSome = $externalClass->instance($SETTINGS);